# Javascript looping over properties with array value not returning expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to access the array value of a certain person property, but 
instead it is giving me the index of the string person. How do I fix this 
to get the desired output?

```
var Stats = {  
  person1: [17, 0],   
  person2: [15, 0],  
  person3: [10, 2],  
  person4: [7, 5],  
  person5: [5, 7]  
};  

for (var key in Stats) {
  if(key === person4){
    console.log(key); //Output "Person4" as expected
    console.log(key[0]); //Output "P" when I expect/want 7
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that you expect `key[0]` to output `7` when `key` holds `"Person4"` (as you expected as well).

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
Stats[key][0]
```

instead.

`Stats[key]` will give you the array associated with the key `person1`. Then you can access the array by index.

For a good article on JavaScript objects, check out MDN's [*Working with objects*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) article.